# Why does Apache constantly shows wsgi error in error log even though there is no apparent error accessing the website

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I am running a website writen in django 11.6.  Though there is no apparent errors, Apache 2 constantly spills out wsgi error:

```
[Tue Feb 05 02:50:57.413059 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 36444:tid 139983401850624] [remote 127.0.0.1:58626] /orchid/species/?type=species&genus=Baskervilla
[Tue Feb 05 02:51:00.107167 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 36443:tid 139983334708992] [remote 127.0.0.1:58740] /orchid/species/?type=species&genus=Baskervilla
[Tue Feb 05 02:51:06.626110 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 36443:tid 139983243437824] [remote 127.0.0.1:59052] /orchid/species/?type=species&genus=Baskervilla
[Tue Feb 05 02:51:12.026706 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 36443:tid 139983243437824] [remote 127.0.0.1:59310] /orchid/species/?type=species&genus=Baskervilla
[Tue Feb 05 02:51:14.600444 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 36444:tid 139983401850624] [remote 127.0.0.1:59442] /orchid/species/?type=species&genus=Baskervilla
```

I am at a lost where to start. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.